# Значение расширения .pyi в Python и его содержимого

Tags: python, модули

Правильно ли я понимаю, что такие модули предоставляют аналог интерфейсов в Java/С#? Или все таки они что-то другое значат?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.pyi` файлы - это стабы (stubs), их назначение и формат описаны в [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files). Эти файлы вообще никак не используются интерпретатором, их назначение - предоставлять информацию о типизации кода. К примеру, у тебя есть сторонний модуль без типизации, который не твой, редактировать его ты не можешь, а прописать типы хотелось бы:

```
# fizz.py

def greet(who):
    return f'Hello {who}'
```

Выход находится с помощью стаба: создаешь файл `fizz.pyi`, который содержит типизированную сигнатуру `greet` без имплементации:

```
# fizz.pyi

def greet(who: str) -> str:
    ...
```

Теперь утилиты статической типизации типа `mypy` или автодополнение кода в Pycharm знают, где найти типизацию для функции `greet`.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что такие модули предстовляют аналог интерфейса в (Java,С#) языках?

Нет, в Python интерфейсов в понимании Java/C# нет. Если в Java/C# интерфейсы являются частью программы и напрямую влияют на ее компиляцию (пример: сигнатура класса, имплементирующего интерфейс, расходится с сигнатурой интерфейса

```
interface Fizz {
    public void buzz();
}

class FizzImpl implements Fizz {
    public int buzz() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

и код банально не скомпилируется). То стабы в Python вообще никак не влияют на работу программы, поскольку интерпретатор их не знает и не видит - они могут отсутствовать, содержать неверный код или вообще абракадабру; проверка типов в редакторе кода сломается, но сама программа будет работать дальше как ни в чем не бывало.

Comment: если такие модули говорят нам о только о типизации, то не легче ли мне юзать модуль typing? или .pyi нужны для более предыдущих версий python, в которых еще не было модуля typing?

Comment: после второго прочтения ответа, кажись догнал, спасибо за развернутый ответ)

Comment: Разумеется, если есть возможность типизировать код инлайн в самом модуле, то проще так и делать. _или .pyi нужны для более предыдущих версий python, в которых еще не было модуля typing?_ Да, `typing` был представлен в Python 3.5, так что если код должен быть совместим с предыдущими версиями питона (к примеру, 3.4 или 2.7), то `def greet(who: str) -> str` упадет с `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Плюс еще есть юзкейс с C extensions - допустим, я написал модуль для питона в C, а C-API питона мне ничего для прописывания типов не предлагает, все переменные имеют тип `PyObject`. Написал стаб с тем же именем, что у расширения, и типизация готова.

Comment: а этот стаб файл должен находиться рядышком с оригинальным модулем, или все стабы нужно отдельно в папке хранить?

Comment: Это, хоть и прописано в [PEP 561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/#type-checker-module-resolution-order), но не особо четко определено и оставлено на усмотрение проги, к примеру `mypy` читает стабы, оставленные в `sys.path` и дополнительно читает стабы из директорий в переменной `MYPYPATH`.

Comment: Если типизируешь для себя, то кидай стабы где хочешь, в принципе, лишь бы консюмер стабов их находил. Если хочешь поделиться стабами с другими, нормальных вариантов два - либо держать стабы вместе с модулями (если код твой), либо делать отдельный пакет а-ля [`typeshed`](https://pypi.org/project/typeshed/), который содержит только стабы (к примеру, если код не твой и мейнтейнер кода не хочет их добавлять).