# Как в python docstring задать несколько типов получаемых аргументов или возвращаемых значений

Tags: python-3.x, документация

столкнулся с такой проблемой: при написании docstring не могу задать несколько типов значений. Например допустим может в качестве аргумента прийти строка, или список строк. Пытаюсь следующие варианты: `:param str, list arg: *info about argument*`, и `:param Union[str, list] arg: *info about argument*`, и `:type arg: list, str`, и `:type arg: Union[list, str]`, аналогичные варианты в return, но все равно при наведении курсора на функцию всплывающая подсказка в PyCharm говорит, что тип аргумента или возвращаемого значения Any. И статический анализатор перестает ругаться, если в функцию начинаешь пихать например int. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Пробовали через аннотации типа указывать (вместо docstring)?

Comment: не, не пробовал. Через аннотации знаю, там через Union, но стало интересно именно в docstring (к тому же дали работать с модулем, написанным не мной, там нет аннотаций, есть только указания типов в докстринге, не охота весь модуль на новый лад переделывать)

Comment: Я не уверен, что pycharm вообще смотрит на докстринги. Если сам модуль нельзя трогать, можно рядом с ним положить файл с расширением pyi, в котором будут только "заголовки" функций и классов с аннотациями, см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012042/1365

Comment: Интересный способ. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

> Что я упускаю?

То, что перечисление нескольких типов в `type` прописывается через `or`, а не через запятую:

> Multiple types in a type field will be linked automatically if separated by the word “or”.

Источник в документации Sphinx: [Info field lists](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists).

Пример:

```
import random


def f(x, y):
    """
    :param x: ...
    :type x: str or list
    :param int or None y: ...
    :rtype: int or str
    """
    if random.choice((True, False)):
        return 42
    return "spam"
```

Тип `x` прописан через поле `type`, тип `y` задан инлайн. PyCharm должен корректно распознать сигнатуру `f` как `def f(x: Union[str, list], y: Optional[int]) -> Union[int, str]`.

Хотя, конечно, прописать аннотации или инлайн или через стабы, как предложил @insolor, решение куда лучше тем, что это стандарт языка, в то время как типы в докстрингах, по идее, должны использоваться только для генерации красивой документации (кажется, с некоторых пор Sphinx умеет вытаскивать типы и из аннотаций тоже, так что типы в докстрингах утрачивают свою актуальность).